# Is it possible to use CursorLoader in an Activity not Fragment with android compatibility

Tags: android

Can I use a CursorLoader in a subclass of an Activity (not a subclass of FragmentActivity) with the android-compatibility library? If I can, how do I get the Cursorloader since getLoaderManager().init(...)  is not available in an activity subclass with the compatibility layer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not unless you are using Honeycomb and above. `FragmentActivity` includes the code necessary to manage loaders, pre-Honeycomb `Activity` doesn't.

Why don't you want to extend `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Large Android 2.1 application that needs to be refactored as the database loads are getting slow on account of growing size. I was planning on changing as little as possible. Thanks for a clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html):

> A loader that queries the ContentResolver and returns a Cursor. This
>   class implements the Loader protocol in a standard way for querying
>   cursors, building on AsyncTaskLoader to perform the cursor query on a
>   background thread so that it does not block the application's UI.

The CursorLoadeer class just query a ContentResolver returning a cursor, so your activity class must implement LoaderCallbacks override the method and return the CursorLoader on the onCreateLoader()

```
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ))";

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }
```

I don't know that getCursorLoader().init(...) you're talking about if yo are refering to the [getLoaderManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLoaderManager%28%29) it is available on the Activity Class since API 11

Comment: Sorry! My mistake. I meant getLoaderManager(). This is not available in the Activity subclass while using the compatibility library. How can I create one then?

Comment: @Ya.Perelman did you know how to use getLoaderManager in activity ?